# Report supplier creation from a particular custom report

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have a requirement where I need to report if a particular role has created a new supplier. I do not want to use a workflow, just send out email to a certain person if this happens. I tried creating a saved search and selected User:Role to the desired one but how to check if the action = create new record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Supplier" = "Vendor" create the following Vendor saved search.  Creating a Vendor search will allow you to reference fields at the Vendor level and System Notes level.  Luckily the system notes store user and user role.

- Criteria tab: "System Notes : Type" is Create, and "System Notes :
  Role" is [enter name of the Role]
- Results tab :  include all the fields you want
- Email tab: check "SEND EMAIL ALERTS WHEN RECORDS ARE CREATED/UPDATED"
- Email > Specific Recipients subtab:  select who to send the email to. You can also send to Recipients from Results
- Email > Customize Message subtab: enter the message details